# Google analytics incorrect data with two tracking code

Tags: google-analytics

i've implemented two tracking code in one of my website. The double tracking code works properly for imps etc but not for **bounce rate**:

1. First tracking property: 60%
2. Second tracking property: 10%

Using the official debug mode of Google Analytics everything seems ok.
**Any ideas or suggestion?**

**EDIT**

```
   <script>
    [..Ga library..]

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-X', 'auto', 'oldTracker'); //Old
    ga('create', 'UA-YYYY-Y', 'auto'); // New

    ga('oldTracker.send', 'pageview');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

  </script>
```

Comment: your bounce rate is too low or not displaying at all?

Comment: Could you please show how you implemented the two tracking codes? If the first tracking code creates any kind of event which is detected by the second tracking property it will automatically have impact on bounce rate of the second property.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about Google Analytics tracking and is not programing related may be better suited for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I've edited the post with some code information @Matus

Comment: Bounce rate is too low @felix91